# Смена цвета у svg path при наведении в safari

Tags: html, css, svg

При наведении на ссылку у svg должен меняться цвет, во всех браузерах все хорошо, только в сафари остаются пиксели старого цвета снизу и справа (картинка)

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40.47" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40.47 40">
        <path d="M18.08 23.2l5.4-3.2-5.4-3.2v6.4zM20.24 0a20 20 0 1020.23 20A20.115 20.115 0 0020.24 0zm8.64 20v.01c0 2.48-.25 3.91-.74 4.72a2 2 0 01-2.01 1.05c-1.03.06-3.64.09-5.89.09s-4.86-.03-5.89-.09a2.024 2.024 0 01-2.02-1.05c-.48-.81-.73-2.24-.73-4.72V20c0-2.5.25-3.92.73-4.74a2.011 2.011 0 012.02-1.03c1.03-.07 3.63-.1 5.89-.1s4.86.03 5.89.1a1.987 1.987 0 012.01 1.03c.49.82.74 2.24.74 4.74z"></path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

и less

```
a {
  svg path {
    transition: fill @anim;
    fill: @c_purple;
  }
  &:hover svg path {fill: @c_green;}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сафари иногда отличается в рендеринге svg, было замечено на фильтрах, попробуйте добавить stroke такого же цвета